# Append List Item Count jQuery

Tags: jquery, printing, count, append, populate

I am using this to populate a list depending on the values of multiple select boxes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() { // <-- bind change event handler to the drop downs
        var sel = "";
        $(".option-select option:selected").each(function() { // <-- then iterate each time it changes   
            if ($(this).index() !== 0) { // <-- only if not default
                sel += "<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>";
            }
            $("ul.result ul").empty().append(sel); //<-- empty() to remove old list and update with new list
        });
    });
});​
```

However, I cannot figure out how to print the number of options added to the list, or number of select boxes with a value chosen. I need to tell the user how many options they have chosen along with displaying those options like I already have. I  have found how to count the number of items in a list using:

```
var count = $("ul li").length;
```

But cannot figure out how to print this count.

Answer (score 0):

Could done this way

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() { // <-- bind change event handler to the drop downs
        var sel = "";
        var counter = 0;
        $(".option-select option:selected").each(function() { // <-- then iterate each time it changes   
            if ($(this).index() !== 0) { // <-- only if not default
            {
                sel += "<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>";
                counter++;
            }
            }    
            $("ul.result ul").empty().append(sel); //<-- empty() to remove old list and update with new list
        });
    });

//The Number of Option's Added
counter;
```

or just convert`enter code here` sel to Jquery

```
$(sel).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make an element and put the value in there, something like this:

```
<div id="count_holder">You have <span></span> options</div>
<script>
    $("#count_holder").find("span").text(count);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        var list=$(this).children(':selected').not($(this).children()[0]);
        $('#result, #count').empty();
        if(list.length){
            list.each(function(){
                $('<li></li>').val($(this).val()).text($(this).text())
                .appendTo($('#result'));
                $('#count').html(list.length);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TAyPE/2/).